# Access Violation Exception in Marshal.PtrToStructure in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, windows-7-x64, access-violation, intptr

### I have below code snippet, which gets a pointer from a C API which is defined in a dll. Using marshalling I am trying to get the structure array, which is my requirement.

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Class vb_menu_dotnet
Public level As Short
Public menu_id As String
End Class
Dim current As IntPtr
Dim outArray As IntPtr
Dim manArray(100) As vb_menu_dotnet
vb_dotnet_get_menu_hierarchy(p_menu_handle, p_apl_id, outArray) //C API call
current = outArray
Dim j As Integer
For j = 1 To 100
manArray(j) = New vb_menu_dotnet()
Marshal.PtrToStructure(current, manArray(j)) //Access Violation Exception
```

---

The prototype of C API is as below:

```
vb_dotnet_get_menu_hierarchy(tcodss_handle_t p_menu_handle,char* p_apl_id,vb_menu_dotnet** p_menu_array)
Structure defination :
typedef struct {
short level;
char* menu_id;
} vb_menu_dotnet;
```

The same code snippet works when both dll and above code is built with x86 option.
But when ran with x64 option i get AccessViolation Exception at,
Marshal.PtrToStructure(current, manArray(j))

Note: Using VS2010, framework 4.0, Windows 7 64 bit OS

Comment: Is the C dll compiled as a 32 bit dll only?

Comment: Hi Tom,
In x64bit configuration, it refers to C Dll compiled with x64bit option. 
The correctness of this x64 C dll is checked, where the required values are correctly returned to VB.net interface.

Comment: Any solution for this issue would be highly appreciable, since its a urgent issue

Comment: Hi Everyone, is there any aletrnative for ptrtoStructure or an alternative for Sys.IntPtr ?